# How to Apply PlotOptions in Drill Down

Tags: highcharts

can you please let me know how I can apply plotOptions into drill down in highcharts? I tried passing

```
 plotOptions: {
    column: {
        groupPadding: 0,
        pointPadding: 0,
        borderWidth: 1
    }
},
```

after `drilldown: {` but it didn't work

```
     drilldown: {
      plotOptions: {
       column: {
        groupPadding: 0,
        pointPadding: 0,
        borderWidth: 1
    }
},
            series: [{
               //  type: 'pie',
                id: 'animals',
                data: [
                    ['Cats', 4],
                    ['Dogs', 2],
                    ['Cows', 1],
                    ['Sheep', 2],
                    ['Pigs', 1]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'fruits',
                data: [
                    ['Apples', 4],
                    ['Oranges', 2]
                ]
            }]
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply these options in series object.

```
drilldown: {
            series: [{
                groupPadding: 0,
                pointPadding: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                name: "Microsoft Internet Explorer",
                id: "Microsoft Internet Explorer",
                data: [
                    [
                        "v11.0",
                        24.13
                    ],
                    [
                        "v8.0",
                        17.2
                    ]
                ]
            }]
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hxua2Lpk/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian Bochan this works but can you please also let me know how to make the columns narrower without padding?  I tried adding but it cause a big gap between them `pointWidth: 2,`

Comment: In case when you set pointWidht, then groupPadding/pointPadding are ignored. So I advice you to adapt these paraemters instead of pointWidht.